# Use the open mapping theorem to prove that there exists a $C>0$ such that $||f||_{\infty} \leq C ||f||_2$ for all $f \in M$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Suppose $M$ is a closed supbspace of $L^2[0,1]$ whic his contained in $C[0,1]$, where $C[0,1]$ has a topology provided by the supremum norm.

Use the open mapping theorem to prove that there exists a $C>0$ such that $||f||_{\infty} \leq C ||f||_2$ for all $f \in M$.

---

This is one of the problems I have been struggling on for awhile now, the open mapping theorem seems so hard to use! If somebody could help me with this I'd greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Actually, do you have access to the closed graph theorem which is a corollary of the open mapping theorem? If so, apply it to the inclusion map $M \to C[0,1]$

Comment: Yeah I do.... Hmm I'm still not seeing it all completely, sorry i'm a bit dense >.<... can you give me a few more details??

Comment: To use the closed graph theorem, you must prove that the inclusion map is a closed linear map. Then it will follow that the inclusion map is bounded. This is the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the embedding $\pi: M \to C[0,1], f \mapsto f$. We want to show that $\pi$ is bounded and by the closed graph theorem that is equivalent to the graph of $\pi$ being closed. So let us show it is closed:

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $M$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2[0,1]$ and $\pi f_n \to g$ in $C[0,1]$. We have to show that $g = \pi f$. Since $f_n \to f$ in $L^2[0,1]$, we infer that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ such that converges to $f$ almost everywhere. In particular, $\pi f_{n_k}$ converges pointwise to $\pi f$ almost everywhere. Hence, we have $\pi f = g$ almost everywhere. Since $g$ and $\pi f$ are continuous, it follows that $g(x) = (\pi f)(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. So the graph of $\pi$ and closed.